# empty() div + variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to empty a div with an id like this

```
echo "<td> <div id = \" $ divbouton \ "> \ n";
```

I pass a variable to a function () like this

```
function activermedecin(numdiv,statut,nummed) { 
    var numdiv ;
    $("divnum").empty(); // vide la div #
}
```

My empty () is not working !!
When I put a fixed parameter like this:

```
$("div_medicin").empty ();
```

It works
Why ??
Thank you
Stephane

Comment: Would you be able to add a code snippet here?

Comment: The correct way would be $("#div_medicin").empty (); - you forgot #

Comment: function activermedecin(numdiv,statut,nummed) {
   

    var nummed ;
    var statut ;
    var numdiv ;
   
 $(divnum).empty(); // vide la div #

Comment: @StephaneVantuykom you're able to *edit* your question and add more code there. Code in comments are very hard to read. It would also help a lot if you would include more explanation on *what* you're trying to accomplish and the actual rendered HTML of the `<div>`. Thanks!

Comment: ok thanks i will test

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove a div's property then it should look something like this.

```js
// single element
function removeProperty(selector, property){
    document.querySelector(selector).removeAttribute(property);
}

// multiple elements
function removePropertys(selector, property){
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(elm => elm.removeAttribute(property));
}
```

If you are trying to remove the actual element then it should look like this.

```js
// first match
document.querySelector(cssSelector).remove();

// All matches
document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector).forEach(elm => elm.remove());
```

If you don't know how to select stuff using css selectors, here's a good cheat sheet: https://devhints.io/css

Comment: Yep it removes attributes. Do you want to remove elements?